# Replace null pixels from one raster with values from another raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, null, replace

I have 2 rasters of the same area, one has some null pixels and the other one doesn't and I would like to fill in the nulls in raster 1 by values from raster 2.

How to perform in raster calculator?

Answer (score 4):

Before starting `Raster calculator`, there is an important first step.

(1) Uncheck `Transparency` - No data value

[image]

You will also note the actual value assigned as the No Data value. (above example is `-99999`).

(2) Start `Raster calculator` and try something like:

```
("Raster_a@1" = -99999) * "Raster_b@1" + ("Raster_a@1" != -99999) * "Raster_a@1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**r.patch** from GRASS GIS commands is a safe way to do this. [See the manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.patch.html), they have nice example with NULL values there.

Notes:

- GRASS GIS 7 commands must be activated (should be by default): Processing > Options > Providers > GRASS GIS 7 > Activate
- Find command in QGIS: Processing > Toolbox > r.patch